# Default Music app invisible by apt

Tags: apt, odin

Is it just me? Default music app is not listed by apt package manager. If you type `apt list --installed | grep io.elementary.music` nothing is found, but it is possible to launch app from terminal. I tried to reinstall, but nothing changed. Also, you can only install it from AppCenter since apt can not find it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the previous answer came about. It's like I didn't even look at the terminal output. Either way ...

The default music application is called `noise`. You can find it like this:

```
sudo apt list | grep noise
```

This was determined by uninstalling the application via the AppCenter, then reading the `apt` history log in `/var/log/apt/history.log`:

[image: Apt History]

Comment: Well, it's not. As far as I know Music app is not packed as flatpak yet.